# C++ check whether is number is int/float

Tags: c++

i'm new here. i found this site on google.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void main() {

    // Declaration of Variable
    float num1=0.0,num2=0.0;

    // Getting information from users for number 1
    cout << "Please enter x-axis coordinate location : ";
    cin >> num1;

    // Getting information from users for number 2
    cout << "Please enter y-axis coordinate location : ";
    cin >> num2;

    cout << "You enter number 1 : " << num1 << " and number 2 : " << num2 <<endl;
```

I need something like, when users enter alphabetical characters, it would display an error says, you should enter numbers.

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: use standard functions:
loop through all characters in the value and check with
isdigit() see here for an example!
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/isdigit/

Answer (score 18):

First, to answer your question. This is actually very easy and you don't need to change much in your code:

```
cout << "Please enter x-axis coordinate location : " << flush;
if (!(cin >> num1)) {
    cout << "You did not enter a correct number!" << endl;
    // Leave the program, or do something appropriate:
    return 1;
}
```

This code basically checks whether the input was validly parsed as a floating point number – if that didn't happen, it signals an error.

Secondly, the return type of `main` *must* **always** be `int`, never `void`.

Answer (score 7):

Use something like

```
if (static_cast<int>(num1) == num1) {
  // int value
}
else {
  // non-integer value
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I'd use the cin.fail() approach or Boost "lexical cast" with propper use of exceptions to catch errors http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm

Comment: The fail method can also be used in strings by creating a stringstream. I.e: `string input; float f; istringstream s(input); if(!(s >> f)){your error code}`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to check input for integer/float/neither you should not use cin into a float. Instead read it into a string and you can check whether or not the input is valid.

If cin reads an invalid number it will go into a failed state, which can be checked with if(cin.fail())

However it is easier to read the input as a string and then convert the input to an integer or floating point number afterwards.

isdigit(c) should be called on a character not an an integer. For example isdigit('1') (Note the quotes).

you can use strtol to attempt to convert a string to an integer. Depending on the result you can then attempt to convert to floating point.

Comment: `strotol` isn't standards-compliant. Furthermore, I fail to see why reading into a string and then using `isdigit` or manual parsing should be easier than checking the fail state of the stream.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: Firstly, since when did `strtol` became non-compliant? Secondly, the fail/success spec of the stream is often different from that desired by the user. For example, the stream will allow `123abc` input, stopping at `a`, while the user might want to reject such input. This is why reading a string and then doing  "manual" analysis with `strtol` works better most of the time.

Comment: @AndreyT No idea why I thought `strtol` isn’t standard. But about your complaint with streams, the solution to this problem would be to check for `eof` also. I still fail to see why the indirection via a string (and maybe `strtol`) should be “easier”.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: Thisng like that does not necessarily happen at `eof`, for multitoken input. I didn't mean to say that with strings it is "easier". It is just more flexible and gives one more freedom. The string, once you have it, is not going anywhere. The stream, on the other hand, is only redable once. Having a multi-passable entity to analyze (the string) is better, in my opinion. And, come to think of it, indeed easier in many cases.

Answer (score 3):

Although others have already answered the question, I'd just like to point out what `isdigit` is really used for. It tells you whether a given character represents a number or not.

Basically, the definition of `isdigit` may be:

```
int isdigit (int c)
{
    if (c >= '0' && c <='9')
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Then, if you have a string `"asdf1234"`, you can check each character individually to test if it is a digit/number:

```
char *test = "asdf1234";
int i;

for (i = 0; i < strlen (test); i++)
{
    if (isdigit (test[i]))
        fprintf (stdout, "test[%d] is a digit!\n", i);
}
```

Comment: Yes. You must also accept minus, plus, thousand and decimal separators used in the current locale (not only 0-9)

Comment: Should probably also accept leading and trailing spaces.  Those don't pass "isdigit", but can still be valid parts of input (though, should be stripped away as early as possible).

Comment: @Jem: The ANSI C definition of isdigit does not check for plus, minus, grouping or decimal separators. isdigit returns non-zero only if the parameter is a digit, and nothing else. Test it on your system and see. A proper number parser would use a function more comprehensive than isdigit, but the purpose of my answer was only to explain isdigit.

Comment: That was the purpose of my comment: one can use isdigit to check if a character can be in a number, as soon as he "ALSO" check himself for minus, plus...

Comment: @dreamlax: ...And you also have to keep in mind potential locale-specific number formatting options. This is a hopelessly bad approach. One should use `strto...` functions to check the validity of the format, not reinvent the wheel and implement the manual character-by-character check.

Answer (score 2):

The input will be cast to fit the variable you're storing with cin.  Because you're using cin on num1 and num2 (which are floats), no matter what number the user enters (to a degree), it will be a float.

Answer (score 1):

Always read the number in a string and check the same as below:-

```
template <class out_type, class in_type>
out_type convert(in_type const& t)
{
  std::stringstream stream;
  stream << t; // insert value to stream
  // store conversion’s result here
  out_type result;
  stream >> result; // write value to result
  // if there is a failure in conversion the stream will not be empty
  // this is checked by testing the eof bit
  if (! stream.eof() ) // there can be overflow also
  { // a max value in case of conversion error
    result = std::numeric_limits<out_type>::max();
  }
  return result;
}
```

It is used as

```
int iValue = convert<int>(strVal);
if (std::numeric_limits<int>::max() == iValue)
{
  dValue = convert<double>(strVal);
}
```

This is a little modern way of doing it :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can store the input into a string, and then create a function such as this:

```
bool GetInt(const char *string, int *out)
{
    char *end;

    if (!string)
        return false;

    int ret_int = strtoul(string, &end, 10);

    if (*end)
        return false;

    *out = ret_int;
    return true;
}
```

GetInt("1234", &somevariable) returns true and sets somevariable to 1234. GetInt("abc", &somevariable) and GetInt("1234aaaa", &somevariable) both return false. This is the version for float by the way:

```
HOT RESULT_MUST_BE_CHKED NONNULL bool GetFloat(const char *string, float *out)
{
    char *end;

    if (!string)
        return false;

    float ret_float = (float)strtod(string, &end);

    if (*end)
        return false;

    *out = ret_float;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Just do a type cast check
if ((int)(num1) == num1){
//Statements
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer a C++ style cast (i.e. static_cast) to the C style one here.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to validate input and needed to make sure the value entered was numeric so it could be stored on a numeric variable. Finally this work for me (source: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/2957/

```
int number;
do{
      cout<<"enter a number"<<endl;
      cin>>number;
      if ((cin.fail())) {
         cout<<"error: that's not a number!! try again"<<endl;
         cin.clear(); // clear the stream
         //clear the buffer to avoid loop (this part was what I was missing)
         cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(),'\n');
         cout<<"enter a number"<<endl; //ask again
         cin>>number;
      }

 } while (cin.fail());
```