# C++ validating float

Tags: c++, validation, input

Hello im writing  my assignment and have it done at all but one little thing is still confusing me. I want to validate float input so if user types char it should display error message.  My struggle is that whatever i do my loop either doesn't work or loops forever. Thanks a lot for any advice.

```
float fuel;
char ch= ???;

if(fuel==ch)
{
do
{cout<<"Input is not valid. Please enter numeric type!";
cin>>fuel;}

while(fuel!=ch);
```

Comment: Check this article I hope this help

[C++ check whether is number is int/float][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784563/c-check-whether-is-number-is-int-float

Answer (score 0):

The way you're trying to do it won't work - since you're comparing a float and char they will most definently just about never be equal.

Try this method instead:

```
bool notProper = true;
while(notProper) {
  std::string input;
  std::cin >> input
  if( input.find_first_not_of("1234567890.-") != string::npos ) {
    cout << "invalid number: " << input << endl;
  } else {
    float fuel = atof( num1.c_str() );
    notProper = false;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response. Could you just explain me this line of code                                                               if( input.find_first_not_of("1234567890.-") != string::npos )

Comment: If the input contains anything other that the chars in the string, it will return the position of that character and thus not returning npos.

Comment: this won't accept scientific format as 1e10, so it does not valid exactly the same way as operator>> does.

Comment: No it doesn't - but the question does not specify that it must either. If that is required, just add 'e' to the string. Not perfect but will allow properly formatted scientific numbers to be parsed as well.

Comment: This would fail on input like 32..32 or 2.4.4

Comment: @user2699298 It doesn't for me (just verified by running it online). So why do you say it would?

Comment: @fredrik Because I tried it on my IDE (C::B) and it didn't work.

Comment: @user2699298 then try it [here](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp11_online.php). Works as soon as the syntax errors and missing includes are sorted.

Comment: @fredrik Just tried and it doesn't work. When I type for example: `3..3`, I get result `3`. It should be error, invalid float. When I type `3.3.3`, I get result `3.3` which is also invalid float.

Comment: @user2699298 See your point, it might be a bit simplistic as an algorithm.

Comment: @fredrik Exactly.. your solution isn't that bad, but it simply checks if the string contains "1234567890.-" doesn't check how many times or if it's actually a float/double. So if it contains multiple minuses or multiple dots, it would take it as valid. Even if they're in not-allowed position.

Comment: I came here looking for a solution to the same problem because my own method works, but it's bad and I hoped to find a good solution. Reading all the answers to this and similar float input validation questions for C++ I have become convinced the language specification denies any possible good solution to a problem which should be easily solved for a language in which, like any other, inputting numerical data will be a very common process. This is enough for me to flee to Python in which the answer is "somevariable = float(input ("Enter your number: "))".

Answer (score 0):

Try code like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

bool CheckFloat( istream & is, float& n ) {
    string line;
    if ( ! getline( is, line ) ) {
        return false;
    }
    char * ep;
    n = strtol( line.c_str(), & ep, 10 );
    return * ep == 0;
}


int main() {
    float n;

    while(1) {
        cout << "enter an float: ";
        if ( CheckFloat( cin, n ) ) {
            cout << "is float" << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "is not an float" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
float num;

//Reading the value
cin >> num;

//Input validation
if(!cin || cin.fail())
{
    cout << "Invalid";
}
else
{
    cout << "valid";
}
```

You can use above logic to verify input!

Comment: Yes, but the in-stream will still contain the number which didn't pass validation. Meaning that when you try again - you get the same error again. Can be solved if reading [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/2957/) question on cplusplus.com

Comment: @fredrik - the code in the linked article is dead wrong. Not to mention that it, too, doesn't remove the text which didn't pass validation.

Answer (score 0):

Part of my source, please ignore 'serror' usage, it's just basically throws a string error:

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    inline double str_to_double(const std::string& str){
        char *end = NULL;
        double val = strtod(str.c_str(), &end);
        if(end == str.c_str() || end - str.c_str() != str.length())
            serror::raise("string '%s' does not represent a valid floating point value", str.c_str());
        if(val == +HUGE_VAL)
            serror::raise("string '%s' represents floating point value which is too big", str.c_str());
        if(val == -HUGE_VAL)
            serror::raise("string '%s' represents floating point value which is too small", str.c_str());

        return val;
    }
```