# Check inputs if number or char

Tags: c++

I am still pretty new to C++ and programming. You could say a beginner of the beginners.
I need to solve an exercise where users can input 2 (numbers from 0-9 / any letter) characters. 
After the user did that the programm needs to check if one of the inputs is an number or a letter.
If its a letter it should end the programm.
if both are numbers the characters should convert to Integers and  should be added together.

The real problem for me is that i do not know how such a "check if number or letter" (if possible without isdigit) in combination with an type convert should look like.

Would really apreciate an small "tutorial"

Thank you!

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/   https://stackoverflow.com/a/784581/11343720

Comment: Why don't you want to use `std::isdigit`? It's literally made for this purpose.

Comment: You may also use  ASCII. Compare each with their ASCII value.

Comment: There are libraries with functions that can do this for you, however I recommend learning about ascii and how the char character works in C++ for better understanding. There are some great resources on google.

Answer (score 0):

Sound like it's your college assignment. Btw Try this
P.S. - there are other solutions too like the use of `isdigit` `isalpha`.

```
void check(const char input_char) 
{ 
     // CHECK ALPHABET
    if ((input_char >= 65 && input_char <= 90) 
        || (input_char >= 97 && input_char <= 122)) 
    { cout<<"This is an alphabet.";/* Do whatever you want */  

    // CHECK DIGITS 
    else if (input_char >= 48 && input_char <= 57) 
        { cout<<"This is a digit." /* Do whatever you want */  

    // OFC ! IT'S SPECIAL CHAR
    else
        { cout<<"This is a special char." /* Do whatever you want */  
}
```

[Read this for ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/)